# Azure EA Deployment

Tags: azure

If there any way can deploy the resources to different subscription from one centralized deployment console?

I'm planning create the resource monitoring dashboards in different subscription, as of now manually I'm importing the JSON configuration file into different subscription and changing the resource values.

Looking for the solution kind of centralized deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Azure Powershell or the Azure CLI. In order to change subscriptions, an Azure PowerShell Context object first needs to be retrieved with `Get-AzSubscription` and then the current context changed with `Set-AzContext`.

```
$context = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId ...
Set-AzContext $context
```

For Azure CLI you can do:

```
az account set --subscription "My Demos"
```

CLI also lets you scope deployments to Subscriptions or Management Group.  An example would be:

```
az deployment sub create --location <location> --template-file <path-to-template>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli